# Stack implementation the Trollface way

Tags: algorithm, stack

In my software engineering course, I encountered the following characteristic of a stack, condensed by me: What you push is what you pop. The fully axiomatic version I Uled [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiNiV.jpg).
Being a natural-born troll, I immediately invented the Troll Stack. If it has more than 1 element already on it, pushing results in a random permutation of those elements. Promptly I got into an argument with the lecturers whether this nonsense implementation actually violates the axioms. I said no, the top element stays where it is. They said yes, somehow you can recursively apply the push-pop-axiom to get "deeper". Which I don't see. Who is right?

Comment: The violated axiom is `pop(push(s,x)) = s`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The violated axiom is `pop(push(s,x)) = s`. Take a stack `s` with `n > 1` distinct entries. If you implement `push` such that `push(s,x)` is `s'x` with `s'` being a random permutation of `s`, then since `pop` is a function, you have a problem: how do you reverse `random_permutation()` such that `pop(push(s,x)) = s`? The preimage of `s'` might have been any of the `n! > 1` permutations of `s`, and no matter which one you map to, there are `n! - 1 > 0` other original permutations `s''` for which `pop(push(s'',x)) != s''`.

Comment: Probably my problem is HOW the axiom gets iterated. If insert the axiom again for x...mmmh, now I think I see it.

Comment: @HaukeReddmann As far as I can see, there is no iteration required. Even after one `pop(push())`, you most likely have a different stack than you started out with (if inverting a permutation is done deterministically, then there will be one input stack that will be mapped back to itself by `pop(push())`).

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, which might be very easy to see for everybody but not for you (hence your usage of the "troll" word), it always helps to simply run the "program" on a piece of paper.

Write down what happens when you push and pop a few times, and you will see.

You should also be able to see how those axioms correspond very closely to the actual behaviour of your stack; they are not just there for fun, but they deeply (in multiple meanings of the word) specify the data structure with its methods. You could even view them as a "formal system" describing the ins and outs of stacks.

Note that it is still good for you to be sceptic; this leads to a) better insight and b) detection of errors your superiours make. In this case they are right, but there are cases where it can save you a lot of time (e.g. while searching the solution for the "MU" riddle in "Gödel, Escher, Bach", which would be an excellent read for you, I think).